# About functional style programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have read a paper discussing von Neuman style programming. The paper's name is [*Can  Programming Be Liberated from the von Neumann Style? A Functional Style and Its Algebra of Programs*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Backus78.pdf)

My question about the functional Style programming languange (refered by the author John Backus) is this:

> Is the functional Style in this paper exactly or approxiately meaning the same things when we refer that of function programming language like **HASKELL** or **ERLANG**?

Comment: The description at the beginning very much fits my impression of Haskell. I guess Erlang is not too different

Comment: "Discussions about programming languages often
resemble medieval debates about the number of angels
that can dance on the head of a pin instead of exciting
contests between fundamentally differing concepts." - Love that comparison xD

Comment: Not really like either of them.  More Haskell than Erlang, though.  John Backus advocated a more function oriented styl of programming, with composition as a major part of structuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a helpful blog post: [Why concatenative programming matters](http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-concatenative-programming-matters.html).

In short, these are two different techniques. Wikipedia calls them [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and [Function-Level Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function-level_programming) respectively. Also there are [Point-Free of Tacit Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-free_programming), [Concatenative Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenative_programming_language) and [Stack-Oriented Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language) - so exact naming may vary depending on who you ask.

As the blog post points, functional (or applicative) languages (Erlang, Haskell, ML, Scheme) are poorly suited for function-level (or concatenative) programming. However, there is [Pointless Haskell](http://wiki.di.uminho.pt/twiki/bin/view/Personal/Alcino/PointlessHaskell) library to help writing function-level programs in Haskell. Note how type signatures for usual things such as an empty list differ from Prelude. The library can be installed from Hackage by cabal install [pointless](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-haskell). See [examples](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pointless-haskell/0.0.8/doc/html/src/Generics-Pointless-Examples-Examples.html).

For relevant languages, see Forth, APL, Joy and Cat. The J language mentioned by Jorg is a descendant of APL and FP.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look at a language that is *directly* inspired by the *FP* language described in that paper, you might want to look at [*J*](http://JSoftware.Com/).